# Function to get user_id's that had their opt-in status changed after processing of the change log

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of users with their opt-in statuses and sequential change log of opt-in status updates that is applied to user list, I am trying to write a function to get a list of all user_ids (sorted by id) that had their opt-in status changed after processing of the change log

Sample Input:

```
        current_user_list: [
            User({
                id: 1,
                opted_in: false
            }),
            User({
                id: 19,
                opted_in: true
            }),
            User({
                id: 4,
                opted_in: true
            }),
            User({
                id: 54,
                opted_in: false
            })
        ]

        opt_in_change_log: [
            OptInChange({
                user_id: 19,
                action: 'opt_out'
            }),
            OptInChange({
                user_id: 1,
                action: 'opt_in'
            }),
            OptInChange({
                user_id: 71,
                action: 'opt_in'
            }),
            OptInChange({
                user_id: 19,
                action: 'opt_in'
            })
        ]
```

Sample Output

```
[ 1, 71 ]
```

My function takes two parameters, but I am not entirely sure how to extract user_id who had their opt-in changed

```
def find_users_with_opt_change(current_user_list, opt_in_change_log):
```

EDIT: users not stored in user list are considered opted_out

Comment: you're missing quotes around `id`, `opted_in`, `user_id`, `action` in your dicts. Please fix that and show `User` and `OptInChange` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
def find_users_with_opt_change(current_user_list, opt_in_change_log):
    current_values = {}
    was_changed = []

    for i in current_user_list:
        current_values[i.id] = i.opted_in
    

    for change in opt_in_change_log:
        user_id = change.user_id
        current_value = current_values.get(user_id, False)

        if (current_value and change.action == 'opt_out') or (not(current_value) and change.action == 'opt_in'):
            current_values[user_id] = not(current_value)
            if user_id in was_changed:
                was_changed.remove(user_id)
            else:
                was_changed.append(user_id)
    
    return was_changed
```

Comment: I get user_id 19, 1,71  instead of just 1,71 -> i.e. user_Id 19 should not be returned

Comment: Could you do a debug print of current_values at the end of the function?

Comment: For big data sets, this will become very slow as if user_id in was_changed is a linear search. The following `remove` call will have to do this search again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python sets:

```py
def find_users_with_opt_change(current_user_list, opt_in_change_log): 
    old_opted_in_user_ids = set(user.id for user in current_user_list if user.opted_in)
    new_opted_in_user_ids = set(old_opted_in_user_ids)

    for entry in opt_in_change_log:
        if entry.action == 'opt_in':
            new_opted_in_user_ids.add(entry.user_id)
        elif entry.action == 'opt_out':
            new_opted_in_user_ids.discard(entry.user_id)
    
    return old_opted_in_user_ids.symmetric_difference(new_opted_in_user_ids)
```

Comment: Could you explain your logic if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure! I build two sets. One (`old_opted_in_user_ids`) contains all the users that had opted in initially. Semantically, this represents the point in time before the first entry of the change log. The other set (`new_opted_in_user_ids`) contains all the users that had opted in after processing all entries of the change log. Semantically, this is at the point in time after the last log entry.
Now the result to the question is simply the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of these sets: All elements that are in one of the sets, but not the other.

Comment: The symmetric difference thus contains all users that either had opted in before and not opted in afterwards (and thus changed their preference), as well as all users that had not opted in before, but had opted in afterwards (and thus also changed their preference).